# ReactJS : <img> tag fails to load image from remote url and transforms the provided url failing with 404

Tags: css, reactjs, html

Am trying to display an image in a react web app from this url : http://chittagongit.com/images/health-icon/health-icon-10.jpg

```
<div onClick={props.info.itemClicked}>
   <div className={classes.ImageContainer}>
      <img src={imageURI} alt={props.info.keyword} className={classes.Image} />

   </div>
</div>
```

While logging the image url, it displays correctly, but after the trying to load, it fails with 404, and in the error it shows the following url:

GET http://chittagongit.com/image.php?pic=/images/copy-right-icon/copy-right-icon-16.jpg 404 (Not Found)

```
GET http://chittagongit.com/image.php?pic=/images/copy-right-icon/copy-right-icon-16.jpg 404 (Not Found)
Image (async)
setValueForProperty @ react-dom.development.js:3135
setInitialDOMProperties @ react-dom.development.js:7749
setInitialProperties @ react-dom.development.js:7931
finalizeInitialChildren @ react-dom.development.js:9000
completeWork @ react-dom.development.js:16272
completeUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:18573
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:18780
workLoop @ react-dom.development.js:18791
renderRoot @ react-dom.development.js:18876
performWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:19812
performWork @ react-dom.development.js:19722
performSyncWork @ react-dom.development.js:19696
requestWork @ react-dom.development.js:19551
scheduleWork @ react-dom.development.js:19358
enqueueSetState @ react-dom.development.js:12789
push../node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js.Component.setState @ react.development.js:354
(anonymous) @ Provider.js:53
dispatch @ redux.js:214
e @ VM1643:1
(anonymous) @ index.js:11
dispatch @ redux.js:613
(anonymous) @ projectListActions.js:22
Promise.then (async)
fetchList @ projectListActions.js:19
(anonymous) @ projectListActions.js:12
(anonymous) @ index.js:8
dispatch @ VM1643:1
fetchProjectTrendList @ ProjectListBuilder.js:67
componentDidMount @ ProjectListBuilder.js:26
commitLifeCycles @ react-dom.development.js:16722
commitAllLifeCycles @ react-dom.development.js:18160
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:147
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:196
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:250
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:18365
completeRoot @ react-dom.development.js:19894
performWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:19817
performWork @ react-dom.development.js:19722
performSyncWork @ react-dom.development.js:19696
requestWork @ react-dom.development.js:19551
scheduleWork @ react-dom.development.js:19358
enqueueSetState @ react-dom.development.js:12789
push../node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js.Component.setState @ react.development.js:354
(anonymous) @ asyncComponent.js:12
Promise.then (async)
componentDidMount @ asyncComponent.js:10
commitLifeCycles @ react-dom.development.js:16722
commitAllLifeCycles @ react-dom.development.js:18160
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:147
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:196
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:250
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:18365
completeRoot @ react-dom.development.js:19894
performWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:19817
performWork @ react-dom.development.js:19722
performSyncWork @ react-dom.development.js:19696
interactiveUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:19984
interactiveUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:2267
dispatchInteractiveEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5081
```

The error only shows for all images from this particular domain (source). If I try to fetch images from other sources, it correctly displays. Tried using postman to check for url redirection. But it displays correctly without any interediate redirection. If I try to display the image in a plain html, it displays correctly there also. Not sure what is the issue here. I did not find any options too, (if any) which I need to enable or disable.
Please help.